# Sometimes scanning BLE device is slow using React-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to `Android` and `BLE`, when I scanned for my `BLE` devices sometimes it cannot find my device. Other devices can be scanned functionally but only my device won't work.

If it works, it took less than 2 seconds to connect my devices, but sometimes it takes 10 or more seconds.

Often happened when I re-opened my app for scanning. Is there anything I missed? (Like I need to clear the buffer or something? )

The lib I use is: https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

1. I tried other BLE apps like the BLE tool, it works and scans really fast.
2. I called `stopScanned()` before I start scanning, it's faster but sometimes still slow.
3. I made an App using Kotlin, but this still happened.
4. I set the scanMode to LowLatency, this should increase the speed.

```
this.manager.stopDeviceScan();

this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, async (error, device) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.reason);
    return;
  }

  if (device.name === 'MyDevice') {
    console.log('Device found');
    this.manager.stopDeviceScan();

    try {
      await device.connect();
      console.log('Connected successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    await device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();

 device.monitorCharacteristicForService(Service_UUID,Data_Characteristic_UUID, this.monitorData);
}
```

I expect to connect to my device faster like other BLE apps.

Thanks a lot.